# Why does the OpenCart SubTotal and Order Total are appear twice?

Tags: opencart

I have OpenCart installed. The cart page shows Total and Subtotal twice. It will not show the final Total too. The gift voucher is also appearing even if a customer has not added it to their cart. Is their a solution? Do I need to edit my settings in the Admin?

Comment: Can you show us a demo link? Have you got any mods or themes installed? Is this just a standard installation? Can you please explain further please.. thanks

Comment: If we purchase a gift voucher it showing the amount of gift voucher and if there is any another product it shows two totals and two subtotals but it is not showing the actual total, is there any possibility to change the admin settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming sub-total is ordered before total. This will check if they have the same value.

```
<file path="catalog/controller/" name="checkout/cart.php,checkout/confirm.php,module/cart.php">
    <operation>
        <search position="before"><![CDATA[
        $this->data['totals'] = $total_data;
        ]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
        // Remove sub-total is same as total
        foreach($total_data as $i => $result){
            if($result['code'] == 'sub_total' && $total_data[$i+1]['code'] == 'total' && $result['value'] == $total_data[$i+1]['value']){
                unset($total_data[$i]);
            }
        }
      ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sub total is used for main price that does not include any tax or vat, and total shows final price that includes all things TAX, VAT and gift voucher or coupon.

and there may be you have not cleared cache from vqmod, so it may conflict your prices and place of prices that you have placed.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth checking what you have set-up under "order totals".  In the admin, go to "Extensions" -> "Order Totals".  In there you can view, edit and sort the various order totals.  If it is not instantly visible which one it your duplicate, then perhaps disable them one at a time, then see the result during checkout, and then you'd be able to see which of these totals is the one you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

the subtotal is your product cost and the total is the amount with the tax or vat.